# How to redirect dynamically generated duplicate pages in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have over 2000 dynamically generated duplicated pages like this:

```
https://www.example.com/subfolder/page1.html
```

and

```
https://www.example.com/subfolder/page1/
```

What i am trying to do is redirect all `/subfolder/all-pages.html` to `/subfolder/all-pages/`

Since it is very complicated to make those pages canonical as i use a custom script, how do i get to do this? One extra question if you dont mind, would that not be too much redirected pages for Google and SEO? It already hurt my SEO a lot. Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to see your existing `.htaccess` file as this would enable the solution to be better optimised for your particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are already linking to the URL of the form: `/subfolder/page1/`. In which case, you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite  near the top of your `.htaccess` file in the root of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(subfolder/[^/]+)\.html$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable may be required in order to prevent a rewrite loop (although whether this is required or not is dependent on how you are routing/rewriting your URLs later).

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - when you are sure it's working OK. This avoids any erroneous redirects being cached by the browser.

However, simply having these two URLs accessible should not have "hurt your SEO a lot", providing you were consistent in always linking to one version. (Unless you changed the URL structure later?)

Comment: thank you @MrWhite , this worked perfectly! i only have concerns now, since this is 302 redirect which is not very SEO friendly, how do i change it to 301? just instead 302 write 301 or what? thanks once again this solved much more problems  than only duplicate pages

Comment: @paranoic Yes, that's the change to make. Be 100% sure it's working first, though!